# Flutter app Keystore not found for signing config 'release'

Tags: android, flutter, publish

I have developed an app using flutter. I have followed every steps to sign my app. I have generated a keystore and update my app buil.gradle. But any time I run flutter build apk I always get this error message:-
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file 'C:\Users\df\AndroidStudioProjects\healthypub\android\app\Users\df\upload-keystore.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

I want to get a fully release build of my flutter app to be publish on the app store.